# Firebase functions logging does not work from non-callable functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting started with Firebase Functions. I made a simple callable function:

```
exports.myCallable = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('I am here.');
  functions.logger.log('I am here 2.');
});
```

As expected, I see these logs in the Logs tab in Firebase Console.

However, I also made this function, which should trigger when the user creates their account.

```
exports.setGroupAfterAuth = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  console.log('I am here 3.');
  functions.logger.log('I am here 4.');
});
```

In this case, I see that the function was called in Firebase Console, but I do not see my logs.

Why do the logs appear in Firebase Console for the first function but not the second, and what can I do to make them appear in the second?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the Firebase Functions client SDK to invoke an auth `onCreate` function.

Auth `onCreate` functions can only be invoked by actually creating a new user account.  They cannot be invoked directly from your app.

The client SDK can only be used to invoke [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), as described in the linked documentation.  The funciton must be declared with `functions.https.onCall`.

Comment: Ah, I should clarify. I am triggering both functions through an actual user account. The former is triggered manually when the user presses a button, while the latter is triggered automatically when they log in. In both cases, the function is shown as triggered in the function logs in Firebase Console. Only in the second case, my additional logs are not included.

Comment: I suggest editing the question to explain in more detail exactly what you're doing that should trigger the second function.  The first one is irrelevant here - please remove it entirely.  The question should contain enough detail so that anyone can reproduce your observations.